# Why d3.extent without parseInt returns the max value of "9" on column num_colors on Bob Ross dataset?

Tags: d3.js

With this dataset (https://github.com/jwilber/Bob_Ross_Paintings/tree/master/data), I want to get the min and max value of the column:

- num_colors.

With d3.extent() I'm able to achieve it, the values are stringify and needed to be parse first.
But why does it return "9" without parseInt.

The possible values are the following for num_colors:
1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15

```
const dataset = await d3.csv("./bob_ross_paintings.csv")
const x1 = d => d.num_colors
console.log(d3.extent(dataset, yAccessor))
// ["1", "9"]

const x2 = d => parseInt(d.num_colors)
console.log(d3.extent(dataset, yAccessor))
// [1, 15]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without **parseInt** d3.extent interprets num_colors as a **string** value and sorts it alphabetically

Comment: I finally did a test by putting the possible values in string and sorted it. The last value is "9". Tx for the hint! Here is the code: const x3 = ["1", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"];  x3.sort();